# Not sure if I accidentally double spent my LTC LITECOIN

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, litecoin, doublespend, transaction-verification, ledger-hardware-wallet

**LEDGER NANO S - CHROME APP LTC LITECOIN**

I just sent two transactions (with different amounts) from one address to the same receiver one after another.

While sending the second the first was still unconfirmed.

The first went through.

The second shows [unconfirmed] and the transaction id [3e454f1dc4a08fdb64ea9e047baf504891934ea8d84ee42732d5d2eebb18e138] does not exist on the LTC blockchain.

Both the amounts of the first and of the second transaction have been substracted from my Wallet Balance.

I've tried following things:

- I already reset the chrome app [SETTINGS - TOOLS - RESET APLLICATION DATA]
- Clicked on [Synch] severalt times
- Waited an hour

I need the following things to happen

1. [Mandatory] My Balance needs to be restored to the amount before the double spend TX
2. [Optional] The unconfirmed double-spend-transaction to disappear from the transaction list

Need your advice, thanks in advance

P.S.: This question is also posted on the official Ledger Nanon Forum 
https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000120894-Please-Help-Not-sure-if-I-accidentally-double-spent-my-LTC-LITECOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem is that somehow Ledger did not broadcast my transaction to the mempool. Don't know exactly why it wasnt relayed.

Solved in the following way:

- Close the LTC Chrome app
- Download the LTC-Version of Electrum Wallet. This wallet interfaces with the Ledger directly, like the chrome apps. No need to import the seed.
- If Electrum gives a read error make sure you enable and disable broswer support once.
- Make sure you started the correct app in Ledger. In my case it was LTC.
- In Electrum go under the tab "Addresses" and copy one of your receiving addresses with 0 balance
- Send YOUR ENTIRE BALANCE at once to your own copied address. For good luck make sure the fees are sufficient.
- Wait until it confirms.
- Thats it! When you start the chrome app again the new transaction will have replaced the unbroadcasted old one and the balance returns to the correct amount.

It should work in principle with every currency.

Got it from this reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/ledgerwallet/comments/7rkicz/bch_transactions_sent_unconfirmed_but_dont_show/